# QT:Как вызвать функцию из другого потока?

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность

Есть функция в MainWindow, обновляющая ListWidget элементами из базы данных:

```
//Синхронизация ListWidget с базой данных
void MainWindow::listWidgetUpdate()
{
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    QSqlQuery query_update("SELECT * FROM clients");
    QSqlRecord rec = query_update.record();
    while(query_update.next()){
        companyName = query_update.value(rec.indexOf("companyName")).toString();
        ui->listWidget->addItem(companyName);
        QVariant id = query_update.value(rec.indexOf("id")).toString();
        ui->listWidget->item(ui->listWidget->count()-1)->setData(Qt::UserRole, id);
    }
}
```

Работает она исправно, но при тестировании на 5000 записей, конкретно подвисает, GUi висит, окно не отвечает. Я в Qt недавно и ненадолго, поэтому разбираюсь на очень посредственном уровне, но я так понял, можно как-то запустить эту функцию из другого потока, как это сделать?

Comment: поток не причем. надо через модель делать

Comment: Я попытался через модель, ListView, но что-то не разобрался с тем, как позже обращаться к элементами этого списка и как там хранить id компании, который достается из бд? Ибо у меня при нажатии на элемент ListWidget'а выводится вся информация о нём, которая хранится опять же в бд